# Xamarin Studio update to 6

Tags: xamarin-studio

last night Xamarin Studio is updated to version 6 (build 5174). When I want to play a project, Xamarin is building the project without doing anything. I tried to wait one hour with the same result.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Also encountering an issue but to open my solution.
Seems many bugs shown up since this release...

You should file a bug to the bug report Cycle 7 : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug?release=C7

The related update topic : http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68358/stable-release-cycle-7-feature-release/p1

Answer (score 0):

I can't say, I fixed it but now it's working.
I launched an old Xamarin setup (4). It checked something and said "Nothing to install". I opened Xamarin Studio and now it's working fine.